# A bug when building CNN model using Tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I now have a picture data of size (419,128,128),which is 419 pics and each pic is 128*128.
I want to build a CNN model to do a feature selection. (p.s. extract 128 important features from each of the pictures)
This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# shape of input data
input_shape = (None, 128, 128, 1)

# Define the CNN model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=input_shape[1:]),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 4, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 5, activation='relu', padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),

    # Output layer, since we need to extract 128 important factors, the number of output nodes is 128
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# My input data is sp_pics, shape is (419,128,128)
data_input = np.expand_dims(sp_pics, axis=-1)

# Train the model
model.fit(data, data, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

# Extract the important factors
important_factors = model.predict(data)
```

Now I'm getting the error message of:
[image: error]

As far as i'm concerned, the error is caused by the shape difference between my input(419,128,128) and output (419,128). Is this true? How can I fix it?

Thank you a lot for your help!!!

I tried different batch sizes and different loss function. But that didn't help

Comment: I suggest edition your question so that it [contains no image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Your stack trace can be wrapped in a code block.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do an autoencoder but this model is not structured as one, the shape of the output should be the same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

[`model.fit`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) first two arguments are `x` and `y`, where `x` is the input and `y` is the label. You are using `model.fit(data, data,...)`, so your input is also your...label?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, in my case, the input is the pictures and the output should be the factors extracted. Thus, this is an unsupervised learning case. But the model.fit() method asked me to give two parameters... That's why I did that. Do you have better suggestions on it?

Comment: In the code, you use MSE, which is believe one element is the 128 features extracted, but then calculate w.r.t. *what*?

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu Have you ever heard of autoencoders? There is nothing surprising here.

Comment: In that case, OP should structure the network so that the output has the same size as the input, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681649/how-to-build-an-unsupervised-cnn-model-with-keras-tensorflow). The current code output 128 features vector, but it should be 128x128 map.